# Are there any memory or table size constraints when using DataFrame.registerTempTable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any size limit for using registerTempTable in Spark? Is the data kept in memory or swapped in disk internally in case of large DataFrame? Can there be issues related to this if I use registerTempTable on a dataframe which has a lot of records?

Is there a limit in relation to the spark configuration (executor memory/driver memory etc) for registerTempTable to work normally? For example if executor memory is 2g then registerTempTable should only store a dataframe of size 1.8g or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any size limit for using registerTempTable in Spark?

No.

> Is the data kept in memory or swapped in disk internally in case of large DataFrame?

No and no.

> Can there be issues related to this if I use registerTempTable on a dataframe which has a lot of records?

No.

> Is there a limit in relation to the spark configuration (executor memory/driver memory etc) for registerTempTable to work normally?

No.

---

I hope the above No's helped a bit, but just to shed more light on `DataFrame.registerTempTable` think about it as a way to register a name (temporarily) that is associated to a structured query which is going to be executed when the data is required, i.e. when an action is executed that triggers a Spark job.

In other words, registering a temporary table is just a handy shortcut so you can use it in SQL queries rather than using the high-level DataFrame operators.